# How to get activity context in a method (java.) for a toast

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android project. for input validation, I created a different class and created a constructer also but I have a problem. I don't know how to get the context of that class in which I am calling that constructer.

> accountmanagement class

```
package com.example.whatsapp.modle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class accountmanagement {
    accountmanagement(String name, String email, String password){
        if (name==null || name.length()<2){
            Toast.makeText(, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    //what should I write here to get context of that class in which I will use this context
        }
        else if (password==null){Toast.makeText(, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        else if(password.length()<6 && password.length()>1) {}

        else if(!email.contains("@") && !email.contains(".") || email==null ){}
    }

    account management(String email, String password){}
}
```

Comment: Either use a global Context or Activity or , pass Context as a parameter

Comment: Just pass context as a parameter to your function. I guess, you call it somewhere from your activity or fragment, so that shouldn't be a problem to reach context.

Comment: if I add parameter `String context` and pass context, I am getting error - "Cannot resolve method 'makeText(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)'"

Comment: Nah, you need Context context not some String, and pass 'this' as value
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context

Comment: @ p2kr 41 working great. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:-

```
accountmanagement(String name, String email, String password, Context 
context){
        if (name==null || name.length()<2)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

 }

// add parameter Context context
//pass context
```

Comment: It works in an Activity, it can't work in the example reported in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Context context` as global variable and initialize through constructor, or you could add `Context context` as function parameter and pass `this` as value.
If you need more specific control,  you could use `Activity activity`.

```java
accountmanagement(String name, String email, String password, Context context){
        if (name==null || name.length()<2){
            Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    //what should I write here to get context of that class in which I will use this context
        }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context